# Asus X399-A Prime will not boot

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have built a system with AMD Ryzen threadripper, and KKmoon 2600w PSU. I also have 32GB of Patriot Viper DRAM and 2 nVidia Tesla K80s.

When I plug in the power the motherboard lights up with some colors but nothing happens when I press the power switch.

Everything seems properly connected, I double checked the ATX connector and the CPU power.

What should I try next or do I have a bad motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the power from the motherboard.  Check all connections, including card slots, cpu, ram, and especially the switch panel connectors marked power and power reset.  Ensure they are plugged into the proper jumpers on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback! It seems the problem is with the Tesla K80s. When I remove them the machine roars to life at the touch of the power switch. Side note: This motherboard has a power switch on the board so it is possible to bypass the front panel.